# Purview - capturing data lineage of data import process

Tags: azure, azure-purview, data-lineage

We have `Microsoft Purview` configured in our Azure Cloud network. When doing Purview scanning of data assets in our Azure subscription, Purview successfully classifiesdata  assets (based on the scan rule sets). But we noticed that when we import data into our Azure SQL Managed Instance using `Notebooks` (inside Azure Databricks) or by using `Azure Data Factory` pipelines, Purview does not [capture the data lineage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/concept-data-lineage)

**Question**: What we may be missing here, and how can we make sure that the data lineage is captured in the scenarios described above?

Answer (score 0):

As per the document below, Microsoft Purview captures runtime lineage from the following Azure Data Factory activities: Copy activity, Data Flow activity, and Execute SSIS Package activity.
When you are using ADF, are you using copy activity? Also, please check this documentation that has the supported data sources for the lineage.
so to capture data lineage in Microsoft Purview, you need to ensure that the data source used in the source or destination is supported by Microsoft Purview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/microsoft-purview-connector-overview
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/purview/concept-best-practices-lineage-azure-data-factory.md#azure-data-factory-activities